# JQuery - Using the Slider to adjust multiple, varying, div width's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I've been working on a custom table control over the past few weeks, and now have integrated the JQuery Slider function to enable increasing/decreasing the size of the rows.

**What I have tried:**

- I tried using the `$('.divClass').css({ 'transform': 'scale()' })`,but scale increases the size on both sides of the horizontal plane and both sides of the vertical plane, and thus overflows to behind the table.
- I've thought of assigning the value of their widths to a variable that is then changed on the `ui.value` of the slider, but when I tried it, it worked exactly the opposite of how I wanted it to work.
- After that failed, I then made this gigantic mess:

  ```
  $("#slider").slider({
      value: 50,
      min: 50,
      max: 100,
      step: 1,
      slide: function (event, ui) {

          $('.divBodyView').find('.divRow').css('height', ui.value)
          $('.divBodyView').find('.divRow').find('.divCell').css('height', ui.value / 1.25)
          $('.divBodyView').css('font-size', ui.value / 3)

          $('.divBodyView').find('.divRow').find('.divCellPicture').css('height', ui.value / 1.5)
          $('.divBodyView').find('.divRow').find('.divCellPicture').css('padding-top', ui.value / 10)

      }
  });
  ```

Now this works somewhat fine. In a sense. I am struggling however with the fact that I have multiple 'columns' in this table, and each column is a custom width.

I.e: `[PICTURE: 50px]---[ID: 100px]---[DESCRIPTION: 250px]---[ASSIGNED TO: 125px]`

Now, how would I go about changing the values of all these **based on** the values they currently hold? Basically, if I increase the rows by 20px, I would have "Picture: 70px, ID: 120px, Description: 270px, Assigned To: 145px".

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try only expanding the first column using this:

```
 $('.divBodyView').find('.divRow').find('.divCell:first').css('width', ui.value)
```

otherwise you could multiply each column with with a ratio variable